# How to get array element just once

Tags: java, arrays

I am new programming in java, i want to learn using simple array object in java. My question is how to achieve this goal as simple as possible.
I have two arrays, first one is to keep football teams and second one is keeping prediction of the team.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String [] team = {"Astonvilla", "Realmadrid", "Ajax", "Barcelona", "Manunited"};
    String [] result={"0","1","2"}; 

    int chooseTeam = (int)(Math.random()*team.length);
    int chooseResult = (int)(Math.random()*result.length);

    System.out.println("Team is " + team[chooseTeam] + " Result is " 
        + result[chooseResult]);
}
```

How can i fix this code that one chosen team would never chosen again.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: What have you *tried* to require unique team choices?

Comment: just remove the selection from the array after you are done, rinse repeat...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First idea, use an `ArrayList` and remove the team when you choose it:

```
ArrayList<String> team = new ArrayList<String>();
team.add("Astonvilla");
team.add("Realmadrid");
team.add("Ajax");
team.add("Barcelona");
team.add("Manunited");
String [] result={"0","1","2"}; 
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    int chooseTeam = (int)(Math.random()*team.size());
    int chooseResult = (int)(Math.random()*result.length);

    System.out.println("Team is " + team.get(chooseTeam) + " Result is " 
        + result[chooseResult]);
    team.remove(chooseTeam);
}
```

Second idea, put the team at the end of the array, and exclude the end of the array from your possible choices:

```
String [] team = {"Astonvilla", "Realmadrid", "Ajax", "Barcelona", "Manunited"};
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String [] result={"0","1","2"}; 

    int chooseTeam = (int)(Math.random()*(team.length-i));
    int chooseResult = (int)(Math.random()*result.length);

    System.out.println("Team is " + team[chooseTeam] + " Result is " 
        + result[chooseResult]);
    String teamName = team[team.length-1];
    team[team.length-1] = team[chooseTeam];
    team[chooseTeam] = teamName;
}
```

Third idea, keep the numbers you have already chosen, and if you get them again, do a new random:

```
HashSet<Integer> alreadyUsed = new HashSet<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String [] team = {"Astonvilla", "Realmadrid", "Ajax", "Barcelona", "Manunited"};
    String [] result={"0","1","2"}; 

    int chooseTeam;
    do {
        chooseTeam = (int)(Math.random()*team.length);
    } while (alreadyUsed.contains(chooseTeam));
    alreadyUsed.add(chooseTeam);

    int chooseResult = (int)(Math.random()*result.length);

    System.out.println("Team is " + team[chooseTeam] + " Result is " 
        + result[chooseResult]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing this way, i understood a little bit the way how array list working.

Comment: I assumed since you asked about arrays, you were doing a homework exercise and you're expected to use arrays.  If it's not for homework, you should almost always use List,Set,Map etc.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use a boolean array to store previously checked elements because it is more memory efficient and (I think) is more readable than using an int array. Try this:

```
int size = 4; // set size here = size of your array 'team'
boolean[] used = new boolean[size]; // all elements are by default false
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String [] team = {"Astonvilla", "Realmadrid", "Ajax", "Barcelona", "Manunited"};
    String [] result={"0","1","2"}; 

    int chooseTeam;
    do //repeatedly generate random indexes until an index not selected previously has been found
    {
        chooseTeam = (int)(Math.random()*team.length); 
    } while(used[chooseTeam]);
    used[chooseTeam] = true;
    int chooseResult = (int)(Math.random() * result.length);
    System.out.println("Team is " + team[chooseTeam] + " Result is " + result[chooseResult]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make another array of length equal to `team`'s length.

```
int check[] = new  int[team.length]; // by default all values are zero(0). If not then initialize all elements of this array with zero(0)
```

Now change your `for` loop a little bit

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String [] team = {"Astonvilla", "Realmadrid", "Ajax", "Barcelona", "Manunited"};
    String [] result={"0","1","2"}; 

    int chooseTeam = (int)(Math.random()*team.length);
    int chooseResult = (int)(Math.random()*result.length);

    if(check[chooseTeam]==0){// check whether team has been chosen or not. (0 means not chosen)
         System.out.println("Team is " + team[chooseTeam] + " Result is " 
         + result[chooseResult]);
       check[chooseTeam]=1;// once the team is chosen then make that check element to 1(mens chosen) 
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much the code working perfect and it is very instructive for a beginner. I have learned new stuf. Thanks, i can't vote on you because i am new hier sorry.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's a good idea to do that, because you will certainly not choose a team two times, but you will not choose 3 teams, but a random number of teams between 1 and 3. If you want to do that, you should decrease `i` if `check[chooseTeam]!=0` to allow the loop to do one more iteration.

Comment: Sorry, but i am getting dublicate

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the teamList so that you can you remove the team once selected.**

```
List<String> teamlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        teamlist.add("Astonvilla");
        teamlist.add("Realmadrid");
        teamlist.add("Ajax");
        teamlist.add("Barcelona");
        teamlist.add("Manunited");
        String [] result={"0","1","2"}; 

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            int chooseTeam = (int)(Math.random()*teamlist.size());
            int chooseResult = (int)(Math.random()*result.length);

            System.out.println("Team is " + teamlist.get(chooseTeam) + " Result is " 
                + result[chooseResult]);
            teamlist.remove(chooseTeam);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need maintain choosen team in some arraylist in the top and check that if the choosen team   choosen again then you will retry again until you get unchoosen team

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches you could take.

**Keep a record of previously picked teams**

You could keep another array, with a list of previously picked teams. When you pick a random team, you could do it in a loop, trying again if you pick one you've picked before.

```
 chosenTeams = new boolean[team.length];

 ...

 chosenTeam = Math.random() * team.length;
 while(chosenTeams[chosenTeam] == true) {
    chosenTeam = Math.random() * team.length;
 }
 chosenTeams[chosenTeam] = true;
 ...
```

*The problem with this* is that the more teams you've already picked, the more likely your loop is to waste time picking an already-used team over and over again.

So you could be a little smarter, and instead of picking another random number, take the next available team. That is, if I pick 1 (Real Madrid) then pick 1 again, I would try 2, 3, 4, 0, ... until I find a team that's not in my array of chosen teams.

```
 chosenTeam = Math.random() * team.length;
 while(chosenTeams[chosenTeam] == true) {
    chosenTeam = (chosenTeam + 1) % team.length;
 }
 chosenTeams[chosenTeam] = true;
 ...
```

There's still a problem with this approach - searching through that list of chosen teams takes time. It's not a problem with a short list like yours, but if there were thousands or millions of entries it would become a big deal. The approaches I describe below get around this; but also later on you'll learn about data structures that let you search more quickly than looping through an array item-by-item.

**Remove the team from the array once you have picked it**

```
 String team = team[chooseTeam];
 team[chooseTeam] = null;
```

Now you don't have to maintain second array to see that a choice has been taken. You can still use the same approach to dealing with finding a null team. If I pick 2 and it's null, I can try 3, then 4, then 0, until either I've found a non-null or I've tried the whole array.

```
 while(team[chooseTeam] == null) {
     chooseTeam = (chooseTeam + 1) % team.length
 }
```

**Remove the team from the array, and compact the array**

If I pick item 2 then null it, it would be useful to fill the hole. You could move the last item in the array to the gap -- this involves keeping a variable to remember which index is the last:

```
 String team = team[chosenTeam];
 team[chosenTeam] = team[lastIndex]
 lastIndex = lastIndex - 1;
```

... or you could shift all the array items down a slot, so 3 moves into 2, 4 moves into 3, etc. Look at `System.arraycopy()` for an efficient way to do this. You would still need to keep a `lastIndex` variable, because whichever of these you do, you need to pick a random number between 0 and `lastIndex` each time you pick.

**Note**

It's a good exercise to do this kind of thing when you're learning. But do be aware that once you move on to do "real" Java programming, you should use Java's Collections API, which gives you things to work with like Sets, Lists and Maps which make this kind of task much easier and cleaner.

A lot of programming courses seem to teach arrays before Collections. Frankly I don't agree with this choice, but here is not the place for that discussion.